# Added Gmaps4Rails to existing site - need to populate the lat long fields from existing address data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, gmaps4rails

I am integrating gmaps4rails into an existing site and have it working well on the production site for records that have been created or updated since I rolled this out, however if a user pulls up a record that was created in the past the map will be blank because the lat and long fields have not been updated.  I am looking for a way to run all records back through the update process so they will have the auto generated and maps will display correctly.

Model

```
acts_as_gmappable

def gmaps4rails_address
  "#{self.street}, #{self.city}, #{self.state}"
end
```

View

```
<%= gmaps({"map_options" => {"auto_adjust" => true, "auto_zoom" => false, "zoom" => 14},
                  "markers"=> {"data" => @json }}) %>
```

Is there something that i can run from the console that won't change any of the existing record data but will update the needed fields?  Would the following get me what I want?

```
Workorder.all.update_attributes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Geocoding is triggered in a before_filter: `process_geocoding` [defined here](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/blob/master/lib/gmaps4rails/acts_as_gmappable.rb#L6).

For performance sake, I'd filter entries and load them in batches, I'd say:

```
Workorder.where("latitude IS NULL").find_each do |order|
  order.save
end
```

A raw approach would be:

```
Workorder.all.each do |order|
  order.save if order.latitude.blank?
end
```